# Does the wavelength of a wave change in the moment it changes direction?

Tags: visible-light, waves

If you have a transverse wave traveling with a fixed wavelength and speed (such as light) and that wave changes direction, then it seems as if the wavelength will be distorted while it is moving, as seen in the red bracket in my picture. Does this actually happen, or is this model of a wave not appropriate for this question?
[image]

Comment: Why do you think something like that will happen?

Comment: Vocabulary wise there is a little bit of an issue with "at the moment". A wave that has a well defined wavelength is an extended event, it doesn't pass the interface all at once. Perhaps "at the point it changes direction" or "at the interface" would be better?

Comment: @DannyH, Remember that a transverse wave moves - it isn't a point-particle that moves through space along a sine-wave path! If the direction of the wave changes (which can be due to the interaction with other waves, as well as by reflection etc.), then the entire length of the wave experiences that change - it doesn't suddenly turn a corner like in your diagram.

Comment: This is a surprisingly valid question. It may bring up the issue that a change of direction does not imply change of energy or wavelength, as the momentum of a photon is considered a vector (in spite of that...). Then the graph depicted deserves more explanation - rightly seen the question is about what exactly is the interaction with material when a photon is reflected or bent (the latter word used with  gravitation). One more thing: there seems to be a "phase-shift" whenever a photon enters some other medium (which may be beyond the question).

Answer (score 2):

The wavelenght of a wave doesn't have to change when there is an interaction that changes its direction. A simple example is the reflection of the wave in a mirror. Also all elastic scattering processes of photons don't change the wavelength of electromagnetic waves (light). Examples are Raleigh scattering, Mie scattering, Thomson scattering.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on "interaction that changes direction".  There is not much reference to be quickly found,  see, e.g. "Raleigh Scattering: Elastic Scattering of photons off of molecules and other (micro and macro) particles, photons do not lose energy but change direction. Has a strong dependence on frequency...", source: community wiki crasic, whereas for Compton scattering "... the change in wavelength is described ..."

Answer (score 1):

A wave (say EM wave) changes direction if it interacts with matter. So the wavelength does not remain the same in general. Think what happens for refraction in the case where $n=n(\lambda)$ and there is also an $\alpha=\alpha(\lambda)$ which is a coefficient of absorption: the wave changes direction and the wavelength changes as well.

If you take into account other types of waves you can make analogous reasonings...

Comment: What if the wave changed direction without interacting with matter? Is that possible?

Comment: Of course a wave cannot change direction by itself. You can change direction by changing the field like in the weveguides, in that case $\lambda$ can remain the same...

Comment: what do you mean by 'changing the field'? I've never heard of waveguides, but from what I can see they work by reflecting the wave off the walls, like a fibre optic cable.

Comment: Yes somehow... It is a system of conductors. In WG you can have also that $E$ and $B$ are not perpendicular. Here you can deepen a bit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveguide

Comment: To tell from the first, user's comment, DannyH wants to know for what reason there is no change of wavelenght, which, as it occurs to me, might indeed be drawn, in the graph, as a phase shift. I just read that there does exist phase-shift when a photon changes medium.